# how do I use requests for the below API calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, github, python-requests

below is my code for calling the GitHub api via curl with python, how do I stop using curl and use the requests library to make the API calls? I'm just confused on how calling the below api endpoints will look like when using requests.

```
def api_request(self):
        api_key = sys.argv[0]
        organization = sys.argv[1]
        print("------------------------------------------People with 2FA Disabled-----------------------------------------------")
        comm = 'curl -v "https://api.github.com/orgs/"{}"/members?filter=2fa_disabled" -H "Authorization: bearer {}"'.format(organization, api_key)
        os.system(comm)
        print("-----------------------------------------Collaborators being listed----------------------------------------------")
        comm2 = 'curl -v "https://api.github.com/orgs/"{}"/outside_collaborators" -H "Authorization: bearer {}"'.format(organization, api_key)
        os.system(comm2)
        print("-----------------------------------------Members and data Being listed----------------------------------------------")
        comm3 = 'curl -v "https://api.github.com/orgs/"{}"/members" -H "Authorization: bearer {}"'.format(organization, api_key)
        os.system(comm3)
```

Comment: use requests https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: I am trying to use requests but I am confused how it will look like when using requests! in the api urls I provided I don't know which will be headers and etc... need someone to help me

Comment: I'm new to web apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm just confused on how calling the below api endpoints will look
>   like when using requests.

Something like:

```
import requests
import sys
import os

def api_request(self):
    api_key = sys.argv[0]
    organization = sys.argv[1]
    print("------------------------------------------People with 2FA Disabled-----------------------------------------------")
    requests.get("https://api.github.com/orgs/{}/members?filter=2fa_disabled".format(organization),  auth=('bearer', api_key))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
import urllib.request
import io

api_key = sys.argv[0]
organization = sys.argv[1]

url="https://api.github.com/orgs/"{}"/members?filter=2fa_disabled" -H "Authorization: bearer {}".format(organization, api_key)
response = requests.get(url).content
```

depending of the format of the answer, you can then try

```
import pandas
df=pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example which might help you:

```
responseAPI1 = requests.post('URL',json=data,auth = ('username','password'))
```

OR

```
headers = {
    'X-ABC-API-ID': 'x-x-x-x-x',
    'X-ABC-API-KEY': 'nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn',
    'X-DE-API-ID': 'x',
    'X-DE-API-KEY': 'nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn'
}
r = requests.get('https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/', headers=headers)
```